# How to run a GitHub Enterprise action runner as an administrator to allow scripts to run with elevated privileges?

Tags: github, iis, deployment, administrator, runner

I'm using GitHub Enterprise with a self-hosted runner that runs on my dev server to accept the build and deploy commands to that server. The build steps are running successfully, but I'm struggling with the deploy steps. The application that is being deployed is an IIS application and I'm trying to run a powershell script I've written to perform the IIS update (stops the IIS server, copies build package contents over to inetpub, starts the IIS server). When the runner executes this script, it fails because it doesn't have permissions to replace the inetpub contents, among other permissions issues. Until now with GitHub Enterprise, I would just run this step as administrator, but I can't find a way to elevate the runner's privileges to do so. Is there syntax for this? This is what I'm currently trying:

```
- name: Deploy
  shell: cmd
  run: |
    cd myBuildLocation
    powershell -file deployrelease.ps1 -inetpubPath C:\inetpub\mySiteName
```

Comment: "I'm using GitHub Enterprise with a self-hosted runner that runs on my dev server to accept the build and deploy commands to that server." Then how did you configure that? If you didn't mention under which account that runner is executed, I don't think you are on the right path.

Comment: @LexLi apologies that I missed your response earlier. It was running as a Windows service on the dev server under an account that does have administrator rights on the server, but I couldn't figure out how to get the service to run with those administrator rights. The answer for me was to disable that service and instead run the process via Task Scheduler where there's an option to "Run with highest privileges". This solved my issue. I couldn't find a way to do the same when configuring the service.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution for this here:
[How to give extra privileges to the runner over the self-hosted Windows server?](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/408)

1. Get the GitHub Actions Runner service name.
2. Elevate runner service from cmd (run as administrator):
   `sc config "NAME_OF_YOUR_SERVICE" obj= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" type= own`